# Alternative link to Joomla admin panel?

Tags: php, joomla, admin

Can anyone provide me with an alternative link to Joomla admin login panel? /administrator does not work anymore - it redirects me to 404 error page.

I have also included .htaccess file maybe i missed something... Thanks in advance!

```
>    
Options +FollowSymLinks


RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})

RewriteRule .* index.php [F]



RewriteRule ^/sitemap\.xml$ /sitemap.xml [L]


RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

php_value display_errors Off
```

Answer (score 0):

That worked - /administrator/index.php?option=com_k2&view=items